# Disable Hover Effect After File Upload with Jquery

Tags: jquery, file-upload, hover

I am using a hack to make a file upload input display the same across browsers. The trick is to basically set the opacity of the upload input to zero, and position a regular input overtop of it, with custom styling. After the user uploads a file, I am using jquery to grab the value of the filename and to store it in the input that is above it (the fake input).

My Jquery is:

```
    var browse = $("#browse");

    $('.wpcf7-file').on('change', function(){
            $('#fakeUpload').val(this.value).css({'background':'#f1f1f1', 'text-indent':'72px'});
            browse.css('backgroundPosition' , '5px -60px');
    });

    $("input.wpcf7-file").hover(function(){
        browse.css('backgroundPosition' , '5px -28px');
    }, function(){
        browse.css('backgroundPosition' , '5px 4px');
    });
```

As you can see, there are two things being done here: taking a value from the .wpcf7 input and storing it as the value of #fakeUpload. The div, browse is more or less a button that indicated the status of the upload. After the user selects the file, the browse button goes to an inactive state.

The problem is after the user goes to this "inactive state", the hover effect below it still remains active. After the use uploads the file (on change of input) I want to disable all hover effects. What is the best way to go about this?

If you need to see my html/css let me know, but I figured it is pretty straightforward jquery question.

Comment: do you implement the inactive state using `disable` property?

Comment: no the inactive state is simply a different image using a sprite...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may work for you:

```
var browse = $("#browse");

$('.wpcf7-file').on('change', function(){
        $('#fakeUpload').val(this.value).css({'background':'#f1f1f1', 'text-indent':'72px'});
        browse.css('backgroundPosition' , '5px -60px');
        $("input.wpcf7-file").off("mouseenter ").off("mouseleave")
});

$("input.wpcf7-file").hover(function(){
    browse.css('backgroundPosition' , '5px -28px');
}, function(){
    browse.css('backgroundPosition' , '5px 4px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Within `change` event you can add a class to that field like following:

```
     $('.wpcf7-file').on('change', function(){
        /// you code
        $(this).addClass('inactive');
     });
```

and then change the selector for hover

```
    $("input.wpcf7-file:not('.inactive')").hover(function(){
        browse.css('backgroundPosition' , '5px -28px');
    }, function(){
        browse.css('backgroundPosition' , '5px 4px');
    });
```

[**Working sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/zHv2Q/2/)

Comment: because this is a hack, its not an actual button or input. The "button" is more or less a background image of #browse. So the enable/disable wouldnt work I dont think

Comment: plus this disables the hover effect all together

Comment: yes, I see what you are going for here.  Currently your code still shows the hover effect. The input with a class of wpcf7-file would also be assigned the class of inactive. WOuld that work in this instance?

Comment: @JCHASE11 demo is working just fine and `$("input.wpcf7-file:not('.inactive')")` is enough

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
$("input.wpcf7-file").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
```

Comment: Im not sure how I would use this....as a callback to the on change event? or how?

Comment: like mawcsco wrote, you have to do it inside the change event after your code, be careful with that "$("input.wpcf7-file").off("mouseenter ").off("mouseleave")" that's only supported on jQuery 1.7, if you have an older jQuery version use unbind

Comment: I have an updated version of jquery, and for the sake of time, I will go with the one that works for me! THanks for your help